# CSS background colour not filling screen using 960.gs in webkit browsers

Tags: html, css, 960.gs

Using 960.gs, I have a page which is a login screen which uses a div for the login form with a background image. This div is displayed below a header which pushes it down to the middle of the browser window. In the CSS I am setting the body colour:

```
body {
    background-color: #594c34;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Arial";
}
```

...which works fine for as far down as the bottom of the div for the login panel/content exists, but below that the page background is white on the first time it is loaded. Once I refresh the page the background colour fills the browser. This only occurs with webkit browsers (Chrome/Safari).

How can I get the page background colour to fill the browser window from the start? Is this a 960.gs issue or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the HTML or the page itself I would think it sounds like a browser problem. You may be able to work around this by moving the background color to the HTML element.

Comment: genius, that's sorted it out. Not sure why (and if anyone has an explanation that would be magic) but it works. Thanks.